# How can I run a set of tests on multiple machines concurrently using MSTest?

Tags: test-management, mstest, mtm

I have integration type tests (not unit tests) which require different environments/configurations. In order to run them I have to create test settings files for each environment and sync the test settings with agent Attributes.

What I desire is a way to have run my tests in each environment concurrently with a single Test Settings file. Is there a way to do this with MSTest? I am working with VS2010/MSTest and Test Manager (I do not have Lab Management).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand it (I'm not that experienced with MSTest/Test Manager yet), without the Lab Management module the way to do this is to install SysInternals to each of your target environments as well as your master/controller environment, then use a batch file that runs the tests.

The basic setup is a batch file to run the tests - you can call MSTest from the command line in your batch file and specify the tests to be run as part of that. Command line options are available at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182489(v=vs.110).aspx

With SysInternals, you can do almost everything you'd do via command line to a remote system. There's more information at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/default

It's a bit more involved than using the MS Lab Manager functionality, but it does work.

Comment: Does this method you describe require anything more than the agent on the machines running the tests?